# Get length of string in TYPO3 Fluid template

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-9.x

How can I check the length of a string?
I want to add a class if under 8 characters.

So something like:

```
{f:if(condition: '{page.title -> f:count()} < 8', then: ' large')}
```

Comment: Untested, but this condition should match: `{f:if(condition: '{page.title} != {page.title -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 8)}', then: ' large')}`

Comment: The f:format.crop example only works correctly if the page.title variable is always 8 or more characters; will fail (false positive) for shorter string values.

Comment: @JulianHofmann Very clever. Works great, except that it should be `==` for a less-than match. You should add this as the answer.

Comment: @ClausDue, I forgot to empty `append`, but otherwise, I can't confirm your concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a little trick it is possible with Fluid:

You crop the string to its maximum length and compare the result to the original string. If the cropped string does *not* match the original, the original string was longer than desired.

```
{f:if(condition: '{page.title} != {page.title -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 8, append:\'\')}', then: ' large')}
```

Attention: [`append`](https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/Crop.html#append) must be set to an empty string.

**Example**

```
lib.stringLength = FLUIDTEMPLATE
lib.stringLength {
    variables {
        shortText = TEXT
        shortText.value = abc
        exactText = TEXT
        exactText.value = four
        longText = TEXT
        longText.value = Lorem ipsum
    }
    template = TEXT
    template.value(
        <h2>{shortText}</h2>
        <p>condition: '{shortText} != {shortText -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 4, append:'')}': <br />
            result: {f:if(condition: '{shortText} != {shortText -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 4, append:\'\')}', then: ' large')}
        </p>
        <hr />
        <h2>{exactText}</h2>
        <p>condition: '{exactText} != {exactText -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 4, append:'')}': <br />
            result: {f:if(condition: '{exactText} != {exactText -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 4, append:\'\')}', then: ' large')}
        </p>
        <hr />
        <h2>{longText}</h2>
        <p>condition: '{longText} != {longText -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 4, append:'')}': <br />
            result: {f:if(condition: '{longText} != {longText -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 4, append:\'\')}', then: ' large')}
        </p>
        <hr />
    )
}
```

Result:

> abc
>
> condition: 'abc != abc':
>
> result:

> four
>
> condition: 'four != four':
>
> result:

> Lorem ipsum
>
> condition: 'Lorem ipsum != Lore':
>
> result: large

Answer (score 3):

You can try it with `v:count.bytes` from the vhs package
https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Count/BytesViewHelper.html

Comment: I would prefer to find a way without extra extensions